# Did I implement CORS at the wrong place?

Tags: nginx, cors

I have problem concerning CORS. I always get rejected from a clients api (Console error at the end of article). Now I'm wondering if its my fault at all. I hope to find the gap with your help.

I got the following setup:

**In my responsibility:**
domain-a.com:  NGINX  ------  ANGULAR frontend  ------ SpringBoot backend

**In the clients responsibility:**
domain-b.com:  /adrstep.json

domain-b.com serves a JSON when calling GET on /adrstep.json. This works perfectly fine when called directly from a browser.

In the angular part I call domain-a.com/adrstep/adrstep.json this gets rewritten in NGINX to domain-b.com/adrstep.json. This is what I get in Chrome:

From CHROME NETWORK tab:

Request from browser to NGINX:

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: https://domain-a.com/adrsteps/adrstep.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address: 212.25.3.166:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADER:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://domain-b.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain-b.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With

REQUEST HEADER:
GET /adrsteps/adrstep.json HTTP/1.1
Host: domain-a.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://domain-a.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Redirected request from NGINX to api on domain-b.com:

```
GENERAL
Request URL: https://domain-b.com/adrstep.json
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 193.246.69.8:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Age: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

REQUEST HEADER
OPTIONS /adrstep.json HTTP/1.1
Host: domain-b.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://domain-a.com
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

NGINX config:

```
location /adrsteps/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://domain-b.com' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,...
    rewrite ^(\/adrsteps\/) https://domain-b.com/adrsteps.json$2 break;
    proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

Browser console error:

```
Failed to load https://domain-b.com/adrsteps.json?: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://domain-a.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Has anyone an idea where the problem may be? I clearly can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my request header...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the graphic posted by @Craft I went in the right direction. But the solution was not on the clients side - it was a nginx configuration error. In the end I had to `rewrite` **and** `proxypass` the request. I missed the later.

Here my nginx location block:

```
location /adrsteps/ {
    rewrite ^(\/adrsteps\/) /adrsteps.json$2 break;
    proxy_pass https://domain-b.com;
    proxy_redirect off;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://domain-b.com' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
  }
```

*Btw: How to distinguish if CORS is not implemented correctly at your or the clients side, just use a CORS-Toggle. If it works with the toggle (It adds Access-Control-Allowed-Origin = '*'), the error will be on your side.*

Answer (score 1):

You should allow the Origin `https://domain-a.com` at the vhost configuration of `domain-b.com` because the browser checks if `https://domain-a.com` is allowed to share resources hosted on the site `https://domain-b.com`.

This link may help you a litle: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flowchart_showing_Simple_and_Preflight_XHR.svg

I hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the graphic. So to sum up, I need to tell the maintainer of domain-b.com to allow or add the `origin` header?

Comment: Yes! Tell him to configure the Vhost of domain-b.com so as https://domain-a.com can share resources hosted on it ( CORS ).

Comment: Thank you for assuring. I will accept your answer when it works.